# how to use polymer vertical layout with margin-top auto

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm using the `layout` attribute in polymer to style my template
here is my code in polymer: 0.15.3+2.

```dart
    .controls {
        margin-top: auto;
    }


    <div vertical layout>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div class="controls">c</div>
    </div>
```

I was expected to see the div.controls at the bottom of my page but it stays in the same disposition as if I didn't apply the style ... any idea ?
I pretty sure I can't use an attibute for that but if I remember well in 'normal' flex it works ...

Cheers

Comment: also, you don't have a semicolon after `margin-top: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

```dart
<div vertical layout>
    <div flex>        
        <div>a</div>
        <div>b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it makes sense why my answer would work, but I actually cant get it working in the polymer designer on their site, which could be jankiness on their part.

Comment: Hi! Yeah that doesn't work for me neither. it works on normal flex though. weird

Comment: what do you mean on normal flex?

Comment: I wanted to say with css definition only